# Apocalyptic horror sci fi short story about child locked in basement

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a short horror story I read several years ago.  I stumbled upon it accidentally while browsing the internet, and read it online as it was described as a horror sci fi masterpiece. My memory may have twisted some details, but this is how I remember it.

The story is from the point of view of a child locked in a basement for a long time. They make drawings on the walls of the sun.

The child is told about monsters in the outside world. There are hints of nuclear war approaching, but this is outside of the child's perspective and understanding.

A nuclear bomb explodes, and the child, protected in the basement,  believes the flash of light is related to the sun drawn on the wall.

The child escapes, and there are badly burnt survivors stumbling through the street. The child picks up a weapon and starts attacking them, as the child believes these are the monsters they were told of.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You say "several years ago," but what year (approximately) would that have been?  Do you remember the names of any characters or places?

Comment: no.  this would have been at least twelve years ago that i read it, but the story may have been older.

Comment: I don't think anybody's covered it yet, but you can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. Sorry you got dinged for cross-posting to the Literature SE.

Answer (score 18):

[A Gift From The GrayLanders](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41375) by Michael Bishop, reviewed [here](https://www.sfsite.com/03b/dg364.htm). It was originally published in Asimovs, September 1985, and reprinted in a number of [locations](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41375).

**The story is from the point of view of a child locked in a basement for a long time**

**A nuclear bomb explodes, and the child, protected in the basement**

From the review

> The abuse of power is directly attacked in "Taccati's Tomorrow," while
> in "A Gift from the GrayLanders" a small child is abused by his uncle
> who locks him in a cellar as a punishment, only for the child to be
> the lone survivor of a nuclear attack.

**They make drawings on the walls of the sun.**

From the story itself

> Finally, though, Cory had his circle as big as a small sun, a ball of
> good cheer radiating into the basement as if the very paint itself had
> caught fire.

Thanks to @FuzzyBoots, I have this link to a detailed [review](https://writingatlas.com/story/michael-bishop-a-gift-from-the-graylanders/), which provides the details of the ending:

> Climbing out, Cory sees that everything around him has been hit by
> some bomb blast: the buildings, the skyline, the dead people littering
> the street. He walks aimlessly, calling for his mom. Then he runs into
> a Graylander. Some hideous, amorphous blob of what could be a man. It
> holds out its eye to him, but Cory doesn't want the useless gift of an
> eye from a blind subterranean creature. Throwing it away, he begins
> running through the ruined Denver streets, away from the beast.

Comment: More detailed review [here](https://writingatlas.com/story/michael-bishop-a-gift-from-the-graylanders/)