# Extremely disturbing short story with glow in the dark faces on a child’s bedroom wall

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror, psychology

I definitely read this in an anthology at some point, but I can remember nothing else about it, except the general plot, which has never left me. Trigger warnings for the following like you wouldn’t believe.

A police detective is summoned to the scene of a mysterious murder in a remote cabin in the deep woods. A young widow’s throat has been slit, leaving her young son an orphan. The son is present at the scene, and is not taking it well.

He seems wildly terrified, unwilling to speak, but moreover, unable to eat or drink. However, he is not exactly refusing food. He appears to be starving. One of the officers describes to the detective that they had offered him a glass of milk, and he took it immediately, drank it greedily; and a few minutes later, looked guilty and vomited it up.

Worse than this, it is discovered later that when the lights are turned out in the child’s bedroom, terrifying faces appear on the wall — painted there, in glow in the dark paint. And a well-used book on animal behaviorism experiments is found in the dead woman’s room.

The truly disturbing and horrifying denouement, of course, is that the woman has been abusing, tormenting her child, consciously and meticulously, ever since his father died and she went mad. She has done this in order to make her son, whom she blames for the father’s death, completely dependent on her for the son’s safety and sanity. In preparation to slitting her own throat, and leaving the son alone. Maybe to spend the rest of his life in an institution.

I swear it makes me want to cry just remembering the details, but I need to find this story again. Thank you and I am sorry, but I warned you.

Comment: Did this story contain any science fiction or fantasy elements?

Comment: This site is for science fiction and fantasy stories. If the story you're looking for does not belong to one of those genres, I think you will have better luck asking at the literature site: https://literature.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I recall a short story I think I read in one of the major Sci-Fi magazines about a (far less) abused child being locked in the cellar. The child paints faces in (neon? fluorescent?) paint on the wall. the reader is given cues that the child does not understand that a nuclear attack is occurring nearby, and the faces glowed as a consequence of gamma radiation. The child is delighted with the colors, and that's about where the story ends.

Comment: @Lexible: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/268635/apocalyptic-horror-sci-fi-short-story-about-child-locked-in-basement

Comment: Yellow paint mentioned in the review [here](https://writingatlas.com/story/michael-bishop-a-gift-from-the-graylanders/)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there seems to be no fantasy or science fiction content.

Answer (score 7):

You are describing Richard Matheson's 1960 short story, "Graveyard Shift".

[image]

The story reveals the hideously depraved crimes of a widowed mother, driven mad because the man she loved died saving their son's life, and so she embarked on a course of irreversible revenge.

[I've added a link to a site](https://mporcius.blogspot.com/2022/11/richard-mathesons-shock-ii-part-two.html) which fully describes the story (from its appearance in the collection *Shock 2*), but your question also relates the plot in nearly as much detail as the Web site.

Comment: In which case, it sounds like this is solidly non-SFF.